# Moodle login page language change

Tags: moodle

In my moodle site english and chinese are enabled. The rest of site changes to chinese when language is changed, but the login page does not change. Can anyone guide me ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the default here

yourwebsite.com/admin/settings.php?section=langsettings

Or put this in `config.php`

```
$CFG->lang='yourlangcode';
```

Comment: can you please answer this question , i am stuck over it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704515/moodle-language-change-when-on-inner-pages

Answer (score 0):

In Site Administration => Language => Language Settings:

- Turn off Auto detection
- Set language to Chinese

Important: The server where your Moodle is hosted may be in english. If you cant change it to chinese, you may have to set the Locale field to one of these:

- ISO-2022-CN (Simplified Chinese)
- ISO-2022-TW (Traditional Chinese)
- BIG5 (Traditional Chinese in BIG5)
- GB2312 (Simplified Chinese in EUC)

And also the config.php setting as Russel said:

$CFG->lang='yourlangcode';

Please let us know if it worked!

HTH!